# Why does swapping the order of a lock and a function not related to the lock in rust cause an error？

Tags: rust

I just got started with rust before and wanted to try to write a Tetris. I ran into an error from the compiler when initializing before writing the game loop:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/game.rs:34:12
   |
33 |             let mut now_block = self.now_block.lock().unwrap();
   |                                 --------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
34 |             let x = self.pick_next_block();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
35 |             now_block.next(x);
   |             ----------------- immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I saw the E0502, it is an error about the same variable first declaring an immutable reference and then calling its mutable reference function. Compilation passes when I swap 33 and 34.

But what I want to know is whether locking the mutex field of self is an immutable reference to self. I think this reference should be the mutex field.

Can't I write code like this: `now_block.next(self.pick_next_block());`?

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct MyStruct {
    m: Mutex<i32>
}
impl MyStruct {
    fn fn1(&mut self) {
        let mut m = self.m.lock().unwrap();
        *m += self.fn2();
    }
    fn fn2(&mut self) -> i32{
        2
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```rust
use crate::utils::{Block, Node};
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use rand::random;

pub struct Game {
    map: Mutex<[[Node; 10]; 20]>,
    now_block: Mutex<Block>,
    packs: Mutex<VecDeque<u8>>,
    score: Mutex<i32>,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let score = Mutex::new(0 as i32);
        let map = Mutex::new(
                    [[Node::init([' ', '.'], (255, 255, 255), 0); 10]; 20]);
        let now_block = Mutex::new(
                    Block::init(1, (1, 4), 4));
        let packs = Mutex::new(
                    VecDeque::<u8>::new());
        Self {
            map,
            score,
            now_block,
            packs,
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        self.create_packs();
        {
            let mut now_block = self.now_block.lock().unwrap();
            let x = self.pick_next_block();
            now_block.next(x);
        }
        let packs = self.packs.lock().unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", packs);
    }

    fn create_packs(&mut self) {
        let mut packs = self.packs.lock().unwrap();
        let mut tmp_vec: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        for i in (1..=7).rev() {
            let x = random::<usize>() % i;
            packs.push_back(tmp_vec[x]);
            (tmp_vec[i - 1], tmp_vec[x]) = (tmp_vec[x], tmp_vec[i - 1]);
        }
    }

    fn pick_next_block(&mut self) -> u8 {
        let flag: bool;
        let out: u8;
        {
            let mut packs = self.packs.lock().unwrap();
            out = packs.pop_front().unwrap();
            flag = packs.len() < 7;
        }
        if flag {
            self.create_packs();
        }
        out
    }
}
// block
pub struct Block {
    kind: u8,
    pos: (u8, u8),
    now_shape: u8,
}

impl Block {
    pub fn init(kind: u8, pos: (u8, u8), now_shape: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            kind,
            pos,
            now_shape,
        }
    }
    pub fn next(&mut self, kind: u8) {
        self.kind = kind;
        self.now_shape = 0;
        // TODO
        self.pos = (0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, it's a reference to the mutex field, but the mutex field is part of `self`.

Comment: Also, please create a **minimal**, **reproducible** example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn pick_next_block(&mut self) -> u8
```

This is a function that mutably borrows `self`. It requires that mutable borrow to be held for the duration of the function call and no longer (as indicated by the fact that there are no lifetimes in the return type).

```
self.now_block.lock().unwrap();
```

[`Mutex::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) requires an immutable borrow of its `Mutex`. That means that this borrows `self.now_block` immutably. The return type of this function *does* contain the `self` lifetime, so the immutable borrow of the mutex *must* last as long as the variable containing the lock. That is, the signature of `Mutex::lock` is

```
pub fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<'_, T>>
```

or, written without the lifetime elision,

```
pub fn lock<'a>(&'a self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<'a, T>>
```

So the lifetime `'a` of `self` exists in the return type, which means we have to retain that borrow until the return value goes out of scope.

```
let x = self.pick_next_block();
let mut now_block = self.now_block.lock().unwrap();
```

In this order, `x` holds no resources. It's a simple `u8`. So we borrow `self` mutably for `pick_next_block`, then we drop that borrow, and then we borrow `self` (technically `self.now_block`, but partial borrowing doesn't come into play here) immutably for the duration of the `now_block` variable's scope.

```
let mut now_block = self.now_block.lock().unwrap();
let x = self.pick_next_block();
```

In this order, we first borrow `self` immutably for the duration of `now_block`. Then we *try* to borrow `self` mutably, but we're still retaining an immutable borrow, so the compiler complains.